# Retrieve GCP Workflow callback URL

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I am trying to trigger a GCP workflow using a scheduler. Workflow Steps can be defined as follows :

1. Make an HTTP API call to another app(Java based running app)
2. Wait for the callback before moving ahead
3. Once callback is received continue with other steps.

Problem : I am unable to retrieve the callback URL for the workflow being executed and therefore my workflow is getting stuck.

I am using Java using which i intend to make the callback call to GCP Workflow engine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you try following the documentation [creating-callback-endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/creating-callback-endpoints#yaml) ? Following that sample you have the callback URL in the callback_details attribute, so you can send that to your Java App.

Answer (score 0):

There a many ways to get callback url

1. post on pub-sub and subscribe to topic or trigger eventarc event from pub-sub
2. post on firebased
3. use another rest endpoint to capture callback usrl as a rest input